# Using array for shorter code

Tags: arrays, vba, ms-access

I have the same line Repeating many times with small changes. i like to shorten it by using an array of objects

For example, instead of this code:

```
StartUpdateStr = "Update tblAfterSale SET "
EndUpdateStr = " WHERE IDAfterSale = "
IDAfterSale = Me.lblIDAfterSale.Caption

db.Execute StartUpdateStr & "Data1 = " & Me.Lable1.Caption & EndUpdateStr & IDAfterSale
db.Execute StartUpdateStr & "Data2 = " & Me.Lable2.Caption & EndUpdateStr & IDAfterSale
db.Execute StartUpdateStr & "Data3 = " & Me.Lable3.Caption & EndUpdateStr & IDAfterSale
db.Close
```

I'm looking for something like this:

```
Const dCaption = "Me.Lable1.Caption,Me.Lable2.Caption,Me.Lable3.Caption"
Public d(2) As Integer

Public Sub MyMacro()
    Dim vntTemp As Variant
    Dim intIndex As Integer
    vntTemp = Split(lCaption, "d")

    For intIndex = 0 To 2
        db.Execute StartUpdateStr & "Data"& intIndex &  " = " & d(intIndex) & EndUpdateStr & IDAfterSale
    Next
End Sub
```

Can someone write me the right syntax? 
Thank you

Comment: You can update multiple columns in a single query: `update T set a=1, b=2, c=3 where ...` so there is no need for 3 trips to the database.  You should be using a parameterized insert to avoid injection vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply access the labels by name with `Me("Label" & i)`

```
For intIndex = 0 To 2
    db.Execute StartUpdateStr & "Data" & intIndex &  " = " _
        & Me("Label" & (intIndex + 1)).Caption _
        & EndUpdateStr & IDAfterSale
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you will be adding many labels in future. So can you use the below code

```
Private Sub PrintAllLabel()
     For Each ctl In Me.Controls
         If TypeName(ctl) = "Label" Then
              db.Execute StartUpdateStr & "Data" & intIndex &  " = " _
              & ctl.Caption _
              & EndUpdateStr & IDAfterSale
         End If
     Next ctl
 End Sub
```

Comment: thank you all. all 3 comments help me :) my code is much nicer now.